# Reducing web app documentation

Tags: documentation

Does anyone know of any good research showing the benefits of designing for better usability and less documentation? We all know that good usability should require little if any documentation.  However, having the research to back it up helps when making the case to those that make the decisions.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Sean.  I'm not so sure "we all know" that.  Documenting consistent styles and standards and patterns helps to ensure that an application behaves as expected and gives a feeling of coherence.  Mapping from an individual requirement to corresponding implementation details to a corresponding section of code to a corresponding QA test can ensure continuity between teams.  Writing things down can help ensure that implications of changes can be understood later by having access to why decisions were made in the first place.

Comment: Personally, I find doing "research to back up" your existing idea to be backwards.  Instead, why not use research to form those ideas?

Comment: I suppose I worded this poorly.  Internal documentation is crucial. Without conventions, we would never get anything completed in a reasonable fashion.  By documentation, I was referring to user help documentation i.e., "Click here for help", Tool Tips and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the metric (qualitative or quantitative) that might be appropriate in your case is Learnability.

From [Usability 101: Introduction to Usability](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/usability-101-introduction-to-usability/), by Jakob Nielson:

> Learnability: How easy is it for users to accomplish basic tasks the first time they encounter the design?

Measuring Usability has an article on [How to Measure Learnability](http://www.measuringusability.com/blog/measure-learnability.php), which discusses how one might quantify learnability. The article goes into a fair amount of detail on what learnability is and the importance of it, as well.

A high degree of learnability would imply a reduced *reliance* on documentation by the user. It does not, however, replace the need for documentation - especially as the product becomes more complex. Significant resources should still be applied to creating good and useful documentation!